# regex on whole string with multistring failed

Tags: regex, perl

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string="string\nstring2\nstring3";
print "$string\n-----\n";
$string=~s/^.*$/_/;
print "$string\n-----\n";
```

The Output:

```
string
string2
string3
-----
string
string2
string3
-----
```

Expected Outputs:

1:

```
string
string2
string3
-----
_
-----
```

2:

```
string
string2
string3
-----
_
string2
string3
-----
```

3: (like /m modifer):

```
string
string2
string3
-----
_
_
_
-----
```

The question: Why without `/m` `^`..`$` broke things ? What i missed in regex docs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `/s` causes `.` to match newlines.
- `/m` causes `^` and `$` to match start and end of line rather than start and end of input.
- `/g` causes all matches to be replaced.

So,

- You can get (1) using `s/^.*$/_/s;`
- You can get (2) using `s/^.*$/_/m;`
- You can get (3) using `s/^.*$/_/mg;`

Comment: in this case why without `/s` `/^[\n.]*$/_/;` matches [nothing](http://codepad.org/R00ZA9IG)

Comment: because . in a character class is a literal character, so you are matching only the two characters '.' and "\n'

Comment: `(?:.|\n)` would be the silly way of doing it. `(?s:.)` would basically use `/s` for just that part of pattern.

Comment: @ysth thank you for this note, it helped me to understand  that `/^[\000-\377]+$/` works as  real all **any** characters (in ascii mode at least)  without `/s` modifer

Answer (score 2):

Use `s` modifier:

> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any
>   character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not
>   match.

```
$string=~s/^.*$/_/s;
```

Comment: I mean without /s what is trying to be matched ?  why it matches nothing ?

Comment: @eicto Because it is a multiline string, your regex with out `s` will only match a single line with could not match a multiline string.

Comment: so without `/s` it matches `\n` as pre-`$` and as '$' is not in `.` it finds that here is many *non-dot-characters* and so, stop matching ?

Comment: without /s or /m, it is expecting to match `^` (beginning of string), `.*` (zero or more non-newline characters), `$` (end of string or before newline at end of string).  The last part fails, because it has only gotten as far as the first newline in the middle of the string.